# What to choose in AppStore Connect ? Does my app use encryption?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

Good afternoon.

I have such a question. When I download the app in the app store, I will be asked:
"**Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?**".

I have a private library that I license for each individual project.

I am provided with project parameters (Application name, BundleID, etc.).
And I generate (independently, manually) several keys, I use for **base64** and **AES256**.
Then I insert these constants into the library.

The library has a security mechanism.
Every time an application that uses my library is launched, it extracts some project parameters, converts them to AES256/base64, and compares them with its constants.

If they differ, it means that the framework was inserted into a project for which I did not license the use of the framework.

**What should I choose in iTunes connect ? Does my application (which uses a library that has a pirate protection mechanism) use encryption ?**

P.S.
I also have a class in the library that contains different methods for converting NSString to NSData and vice versa.
Below it will be .h file. I only use a part of them, just to check the license.

**THE LICENSE is checked locally on the device ! I don't send the data anywhere.**

```objectivec
/*-------------------------------------------------
 CommonHMAC
 --------------------------------------------------*/
@interface NSData (CommonHMAC)
- (NSData*) HMACWithAlgorithm:(CCHmacAlgorithm) algorithm;
- (NSData*) HMACWithAlgorithm:(CCHmacAlgorithm) algorithm key:(id)key;
@end

/*---------------------------------------------------------
 CommonCryptor
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
@interface NSData (CommonCryptor)
- (NSData*) AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey:(id)key error:(NSError **) error;
- (NSData*) decryptedAES256DataUsingKey:(id)key error:(NSError **) error;
- (NSData*) DESEncryptedDataUsingKey:(id)key    error:(NSError **) error;
- (NSData*) decryptedDESDataUsingKey:(id)key    error:(NSError **) error;
- (NSData*) CASTEncryptedDataUsingKey:(id)key   error:(NSError **) error;
- (NSData*) decryptedCASTDataUsingKey:(id)key   error:(NSError **) error;
@end

/*--------------------------------------------------------
 CommonDigest
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
@interface NSData (CommonDigest)
- (NSData*) MD2Sum;
- (NSData*) MD4Sum;
- (NSData*) MD5Sum;
- (NSData*) SHA1Hash;
- (NSData*) SHA224Hash;
- (NSData*) SHA256Hash;
- (NSData*) SHA384Hash;
- (NSData*) SHA512Hash;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides good guidance here: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev88f5c7bf9

If you're based in the US, you can also review US Department of Commerce information here: https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/regulations-docs/445-category-5-part-2-information-security

The TLDR from Apple's guidelines is:
Use of encryption includes, but is not limited to:

- Making calls over secure channels (i.e. HTTPS, SSL, and so on).
- Using standard encryption algorithms.
- Using crypto functionality from other sources such as iOS or macOS.
- Using proprietary or non-standard encryption algorithms.

So all of us building apps that make an **HTTPS** call to an API, should be answering **Yes** to this question.